# HTML table layout make more gap

Tags: html, css

HTML table code for my page is here.
It's not automatically adjust. I need to remove the extra spaces and only 5% space between them have to remain.

```
<table width="95%">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnTargetVsActual" runat="server" Text="Target Vs Actual" CssClass="selectedButton"
                        Width="200px" OnClientClick="javascript:return SetFilterAndChart('ctl00_CPHFFR_btnTargetVsActual');" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnKPIActivities" runat="server" Text="KPI Activities" CssClass="unSelectedButton"
                        Width="200px" OnClientClick="javascript:return SetFilterAndChart('ctl00_CPHFFR_btnKPIActivities');" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100%;white-space: nowrap;">
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlMain" runat="server" BorderColor="Navy" BorderWidth="2">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdFilters" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlFilterCriteria" runat="server" GroupingText="Filter Criteria" BorderWidth="1">
                                    <table width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" id="tdlblYear">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblYear" runat="server" Text="Year" CssClass="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center" id="tdlblMonth">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblMonth" runat="server" Text="Month" CssClass="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center" id="tdlblCountry">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text="Country" CssClass="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center" id="tdlblDivision">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblDivision" runat="server" Text="Team" CssClass="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center" id="tdlblPosition">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblPosition" runat="server" Text="Position" CssClass="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center" id="tdlblClass" >
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblClass" runat="server" Text="Class" CssClass="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center" id="tdlblSpecialty">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblSpecialty" runat="server" Text="Specialty" CssClass="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style ="white-space: nowrap;">
                                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server" CssClass="dropDownList" Width="98%" >
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlMonth" ScrollBars="Auto" runat="server" Height="95px" BorderColor="#003973"
                                                    BorderWidth="1px" Width="95%">
                                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblMonth" runat="server" CssClass="checkboxlist">
                                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" CssClass="dropDownList" Width="95%"
                                                    AutoPostBack="true">
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlDivision" ScrollBars="Auto" runat="server" Height="95px" BorderColor="#003973"
                                                    BorderWidth="1px" Width="95%">
                                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblDivision" runat="server" CssClass="checkboxlist" AutoPostBack="true">
                                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPosition" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPosition" ScrollBars="Auto" runat="server" Height="95px" BorderColor="#003973"
                                                            BorderWidth="1px" width="95%">
                                                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblPosition" runat="server" CssClass="checkboxlist">
                                                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                                        </asp:Panel>
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                    <Triggers>
                                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cblDivision" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                                    </Triggers>
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top" >                                        
                                                <center>
                                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlClass" runat="server" Height="95px" BorderColor="#003973" BorderWidth="1px"
                                                    Width="35%">                                                
                                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblClass" runat="server" CssClass="checkboxlist">
                                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                                </center>                                         
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSpecialty" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlSpecialty" ScrollBars="Auto" runat="server" Height="95px" BorderColor="#003973"
                                                            BorderWidth="1px" >
                                                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblSpecialty" runat="server" CssClass="checkboxlist">
                                                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                                        </asp:Panel>

                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                    <Triggers>
                                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cblDivision" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                                    </Triggers>
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="padding: 5px;">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="GO" CssClass="button" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table id="tblTargetVsActual" width="100%" runat="server">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <div id="divSellingDays">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <div id="divFrequency">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <div id="divCoverage">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table id="tblKPIActivities" width="100%" runat="server">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 50%;" valign="top">
                                    <div id="divCallVolume">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 50%;" valign="top">
                                    <div id="divFrequencyByDoctor">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 50%;" valign="top">
                                    <div id="divCallVolumeByClass">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 50%;" valign="top">
                                    <div id="divDoctorCoverageByClass">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 50%;" valign="top">
                                    <div id="divFrequencyByClass">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 50%;" valign="top">
                                    <div id="divDailyCallRate">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and output of this code is generated like below
[image]

I need to remove that gaps and assign the space to "position" and "speciality".

thanks in advance!
--------------EDIT----- CSS rules

```
.dropDownList

    {
        font-size: 11px;
        font-style: normal; /*font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;*/
        font-family: Arial;
        color: Navy;
        border: Solid;
        border-color: Navy;
        border-width: 1px;
        width: 150px;
        line-height: 12px;
        height: 20px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .checkboxlist
    {
        font-size: 11px;
        font-style: normal;
        /*font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;*/
        font-family: Arial;
    }
```

Comment: It would be good to see your CSS rules

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u make the table with selection of values look this way:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr width="100%">
    <td width="14%">Year</td>
    <td width="14%">Month</td>
    <td width="14%">Country</td>
    <td width="14%">Team</td>
    <td width="16%">Position</td>
    <td width="7%">Class</td>
    <td width="16%">Speciality</td>
</tr>    

<tr width="100%">
    <td width="14%">2013</td>
    <td width="14%">January<br />June</td>
    <td width="14%">All countries</td>
    <td width="14%">All teams</td>
    <td width="16%">Position</td>
    <td width="7%">A</td>
    <td width="16%">All speciality</td>
</tr>
```

Making each cell in row same width in percents(percents of the row), the class smaller and the position and speciality wider.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/XXSMA/2/

I made just basic table. I don't have your resources but implementation to your code shouldn't be a problem.

Also I noticed that you are assigning 35% width to the Class. Maybe if u give 125% to Position and Speciality it might work too. But I think that dividing 100% of the row partially to each cell in row is better.

Comment: may be that's not possible for my code bcoz,at runtime later need to remove "class" and "speciality".this is only initially successful.but later it's not gone work.

Comment: Uh, well that complicates it a bit :|.

Comment: MY Apologies, it happen bcoz one java script which is run in page load method. it make calculated width for all attribute.I solved the problem by just changing it. document.getElementById('tdlblClass').style.width = "6%";